# Use part of column name to split a dataframe into 3 new ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three different types (name-wise) of variables. I want to use the names of the variables as filter and split the dataframe in 3 new dataframes. In my first dataframe I want PERIOD, A, B, C. In my second I want PERIOD, A_TREND, B_TREND, C_TREND and in my third I want PERIOD, A_Seasonally_Adjusted, B_Seasonally_Adjusted, C_Seasonally_Adjusted.

I'm looking here for specific solution that uses the information in the column names (_Trend & _Seasonally_Adjusted) in a generic way to acheive the above.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['2021-04', 1, 12, 33, 2, 35, 6, 3, 8, 90], 
                       ['2021-05', 4, 98, 9, 5, 82, 94, 82, 9, 21],
                       ['2021-06', 81, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 3, 72]]),
                   columns=['PERIOD', 'A', 'B', 'C', 
                            'A_Trend', 'A__Seasonally Adjusted', 
                            'B_Trend', 'B__Seasonally Adjusted', 
                            'C_Trend', 'C__Seasonally Adjusted'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.filter` with `like`

```
trend_df = df.filter(like='Trend')
season_df = df.filter(like='Seasonally Adjusted')


print(trend_df)

  A_Trend B_Trend C_Trend
0       2       6       8
1       5      94       9
2       8       9       3

print(season_df)

  A__Seasonally Adjusted B__Seasonally Adjusted C__Seasonally Adjusted
0                     35                      3                     90
1                     82                     82                     21
2                      9                      8                     72
```

---

then take the delta to get your starting columns.

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(season_df.columns.tolist() + trend_df.columns.tolist())]

    PERIOD   A   B   C
0  2021-04   1  12  33
1  2021-05   4  98   9
2  2021-06  81   9   8
```

---

if you want `Period` in all the dataframes, first set to the index

```
df.set_index('Period') #or
df.set_index('Period',append=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works brilliant. Why don't I need to set axis=1?

Comment: @Henrik from my experience the default is usually the columns, but feel free to add it in. If you changed it to 0 it would filter the labels of the index.